# How do I can skip a duplicate value before adding it to the database?

Tags: php, laravel

I have table with favorites programm. I will add with ajax query to database favorite programm id's to table with user id. How I can skip a duplicate programm id with current user id. 
I now create this method for skip duplicate values but not working in calling:

```
public function test($programm_id){
    $fav = new \App\Favorite;
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $fav_count = $fav::where('id_user', Auth::user()->id)->count();
    $getFavorites = $fav::where('id_user', $user_id)->get()->toArray();
    $userProgramms = $fav->where('id_user', $user_id)->select('id_program')->get()->toArray();
    $bool = true;
    foreach ($userProgramms as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            if($value === $programm_id) $bool = false;
        }
    }

    if($fav_count <= 5){   
        if ($bool){
             $fav->id_user = Auth::user()->id;
             $fav->id_program = $programm_id; 
             $fav->save();
        }                  
    }
}
```

Here my table:

[image]

Please see my method `favorite()` in this controller: [Controller](https://3v4l.org/O855r)

My updated code can't more 1 saves to database.

```
$fav = new \App\Favorite;
$fav_count = $fav::where('id_user', Auth::user()->id)->count();
if($fav_count <= 5)
{
  $fav->updateOrInsert(['id_user' => Auth::id()], ['id_program' => $post['id_program']]);
}
```

Every user can add to table max 6 favorite id programms

Comment: If I use in code this code `ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`id_user`, `id_program`);` and laravel method `$fav->updateOrInsert(['id_user' => Auth::id()], ['id_program' => $post['id_program']]);` it is work incorrect

Comment: Every user can be add max 6 favorite unique programm id's. Now only one programm addind and second or more not inserted

Answer (score 0):

Add an unique index on the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`id_user`, `id_program`);
```

and use the [`INSERT INTO ... OR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE t1 SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

In that manner your query will insert a new record if there isn't already a record with the same couple of `id_user` and `id_program` values, in case of it it'll perform an update on that row.

Comment: It is not working correctly. Because with your code one user can't insert more one data to database @user2342558

Comment: @MaxNet, did you read the question? The aim is to AVOID two rows with same `id_user` and `id_program`

Comment: Here id user can be repeat but not program id with that user id's

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in PHP and assuming your values are stored in an array, you can use `array_unique()`.

Check it out here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php